# QTP stops recording actions after Security Window dialog closes

Tags: automated-testing, web-application, qtp, action-recording

I am recording user scenario using QTP 11.0. So I have set up URL to open in IE 11 in `Record and Run Settings`.

After starting record Security Windows dialog pops up over IE window:

[image]

I fill in all the information and click 'OK'. All the actions are displayed in test recording window:

[image]

Here is generated VB Script:

```
Window("Internet Explorer_2").Dialog("Безопасность Windows").WinEdit("Edit").Set "login"
Window("Internet Explorer_2").Dialog("Безопасность Windows").WinEdit("Edit").Type  micTab 
Window("Internet Explorer_2").Dialog("Безопасность Windows").WinEdit("Edit_2").SetSecure "55e843e24276e91e"
Window("Internet Explorer_2").Dialog("Безопасность Windows").WinEdit("Edit_2").Type  micTab 
Window("Internet Explorer_2").Dialog("Безопасность Windows").WinObject("DirectUIHWND").Type  micTab 
Window("Internet Explorer_2").Dialog("Безопасность Windows").WinButton("ОК").Type  micReturn
```

But after the authorization is complited and web-page is loaded, not a single action is recorded. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

**Researches till now:**

Checked `Object Identification...` parameters for Web:

[image]

Checked `Web Event Recording Configuration...`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

QTP 11.0 does not support IE11.

The first version that supporto IE11 is UFT 12.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but only a posible workaround:

The URL spec supports passing username & password, so that you don't have to enter it manually (in the security popup, which seems to cause the problem). In your automation, you could try navigating to the URL as follows:

```
http://login:password@your.url.ru
```

where login is your username and password is the password

However in Internet Explorer MS disabled that feature, so you need to enable it manually, [as described here.](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.fr/2013/09/dealing-with-http-basic-authentication.html)

After enabling it as described in the linked article, you're better off testing it yourself before feeding the URL through your automation, so that you're 100% sure it works.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! But as I figured out the broblem is more global: QTP does not record web-actions at all.